# С# Windows Forms Как сделать так чтобы, при нажатии кнопки пользователь выбрал куда установить .exe файл

Tags: c#

Можете объяснить всё по пунктам, что нужно сделать для того чтобы при нажатии кнопки у пользователя высвечивалось окно куда устанавливать .exe файл.

Comment: использовать SaveFileDialog или SelectFolderDialog

Comment: Возможно, ваш вопрос про то, как создать инсталлятор?

Answer (score 3):

Для подобных диалогов в C# есть класс [CommonDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.commondialog), от которого базируются уже все остальные диалоги (их список вы можете увидеть в документации).

Если вам нужно *сохранить файл*, то тут скорей всего нужен [SaveFileDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog).

Реализация у всех диалогов +- одинакова, я покажу самую базовую:

```
using(var dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
{
    var dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dialog.FileName;
    }
}
```

Тут все довольно просто:

- Инициализируем класс `SaveFileDialog()` (что бы не беспокоится о его удаление, делаем это в `using`).
- Далее мы вызываем (`.ShowDialog()`) само окно и полученный результат (какую кнопку нажали) записываем в переменную.
- Проверяем результат. Если пользователь нажал "ОК", то вытаскиваем из диалога нужное нам значение и записываем его, например в `TextBox`.

Вот и все, у нас готов полноценный диалог для выбора пути сохранения файла.
Остальные диалоги по сути реализуются точно также, отличия только в получение данных. Если пойти чуть дальше, то мы можем например все это превратить в один метод, что то по типу:

```
private string ShowDialog<T>() where T : CommonDialog, new()
{
    string result = null;
    using(var dialog = new T())
    {
        var dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if(dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if(dialog is FileDialog fileDialog)
                result = fileDialog.FileName;
            if(dialog is FolderBrowserDialog folderDial)
                result = folderDial.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Тогда вызов нашего (любого) диалога будет выглядеть так:

```
textBox1.Text = ShowDialog<SaveFileDialog>();
```

В общем удачи в изучение C# как говорится.